# Problem during Installing Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS alongside windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

My brother gave me his laptop to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10.

First of all, I've separated an area for installing Ubuntu and make bootable USB using Etcher.

Then Made three partition as follows:

```
swap area
ext4 for '/'
and an efi System partition
```

Then I've Installed the Ubuntu.

It installed successfully. But when I restart there appears a grub shell and says:

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _
```

N.B.

- The hard disk is partitioned with MBR format. And have already three
  drive for Windows. I don't know how extra three drive is created during Ubuntu installation!
- The system supports BIOS and UEFI. I have
  installed in both mode but same output...
- I've also tried installing ubuntu by creating only one partition. But it warns me to create an `Efi System Partition` otherwise it may fail to boot.

And now I can't boot into Windows also.

The output of `sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA HGST HTS541010A7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  525MB   524MB   primary   ntfs
 2      525MB   108GB   108GB   primary   ntfs
 3      108GB   1000GB  892GB   extended                  lba
 9      108GB   109GB   499MB   logical   fat32           boot, esp
10      109GB   323GB   214GB   logical   ext4
 8      323GB   331GB   8193MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 5      331GB   554GB   223GB   logical   ntfs
 6      554GB   777GB   223GB   logical   ntfs
 7      777GB   1000GB  223GB   logical   ntfs


Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Ignore/Cancel?                                                            
Ignore/Cancel? I                                                          
Model: SMI USB DISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 126GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/512B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B   6143B   4096B                Apple
 2      1961MB  1964MB  2523kB               EFI
```

Comment: Why do you have MBR partitioning, when Windows 10 defaults to GPT? FYI, a swap partition is passe unless you intend to turn on Hibernation for Ubuntu after you complete installation. The standard installation process generates a swap file automatically sized based on your available RAM.

Comment: From Live Ubuntu run `sudo parted -l`, and post output into question.

Comment: output of `sudo parted -l` added

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows is on an MSDOs partitioned disk, so it's installed in legacy mode. You should install Ubuntu in legacy mode too.  How you install is determined by how you boot the install media, so check your BIOs/UEFI settings and select the preferred boot mechanism -- legacy.  You wont need an efi partition.  You wont need a grub-bios partition either. All your Ubuntu install may on on logical paritions.  You made one 214G ext4 (and a swap).  Are the ntfs logical partitions ones you made?
This should be a standard legacy install, but your UEFI capable machine complicates things.  A Windows 7 (legacy) upgraded to W8 then W10 will result in your type of setup -- Windows 10 on a MSDOS parttiioned disk.

---

The FAT32 partition is not needed, and if you don't delete it, you should at least remove the boot and esp flags.  Windows may need the boot flag on its partition, Ubuntu doens't care.  If you get rid of the swap partition too, think about how you want to divide the 222GB for Ubuntu -- 25-50GB for root, rest a data partition ( or /home).  Or just keep it all one big partition, whatever meets your needs best. There are many recommendations for disk partitioning.

---

ESP warnings are a sure sign you are booting the install media in UEFI mode.  Recheck your BIOS/UEFI settings, they vary by machine. Some allow you to select a preferred mode (select legacy) when both are present. Some are more obscure, like selecting CSM mode.  Legacy knows nothing about ESPs, so shouldn't complain.

Comment: The NTFS partitions created before installing Ubuntu and I've created only the #8 #9 & #10 partitions for Installing Ubuntu.

Comment: But in legacy mode also warns me about the ESP partition.